# Error passing in SSIS package variables from job command line in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssms

I'm trying to have a job pass in a variable for multiple emails through the command line in SQL Server ManageMent Studio however, it is throwing an error for a specific SET call. FYI, User::gEmailTo is a string in the package.

In my job creation script, I have the following -

--Declaration

:setvar EmailTo "josh@test.com; mike@test.com; earl@test.com; mark@test.com; bill@test.com"

--Syntax throwing the error:

```
'/SET "\package.Variables[User::gEmailTo].Value";"$(EmailTo)" '
```

The output in the command line for the job in SSMS shows:

```
/SET "\"\package.Variables[User::gEmailTo].Value\"";"\"josh@test.com; mike@test.com; earl@test.com; mark@test.com; bill@test.com\""
```

The error

```
Argument ""\package.Variables[User::gEmailTo].Value;josh@test.com; mike@test.com; earl@test.com; mark@test.com; bill@test.com"" for option "set" is not valid.  The command line parameters are invalid.  The step failed.
```

Comment: Can you share the error message, it would be helpful.

Comment: Are you getting the error when you try to CREATE the job, or when you try to EXECUTE it?

Comment: I am getting the error when I execute the job. The package does not run at all because apparently this command line parameter is invalid.

Comment: I am unsure but I think it has something to do with the EmailTo variable. It has to be enclosed by quotation marks so it doesn't throw errors(semicolon and spaces). Other variables being passed in don't do this because it's not necessary. How this variable is handled in the /SET command might be causing the error, but I'm not sure how to fix it if this is so.